# div height mismatch in display and jquery .height() function

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

How to calculate the displayed div height.
.height() method is fetching the height which is less than the displayed height.

Comment: Read the `.height()` docs, it spells out how it works.

Comment: I read it and implemented. Found no solution. So posted the question here.

Answer (score 0):

use `.scrollHeight`:

```
$('#divid')[0].scrollHeight
```